# Optical Smoke Detector design with Arduino: buzzer problem

Tags: arduino, detector, smoke-sensor

I'm working on an **Optical Smoke Detector** using Arduino UNO board. Here is the circuit diagram:

[image]

Whenever smoke is detected by the smoke sensor, the buzzer and LED should work. From the Arduino board, I'm only controlling the smoke sensor. When I run simulation of the circuit, the buzzer and the LED is not working. Though, the smoke sensor works fine. Here is an screenshot of the serial monitor:

[image]

The higher values means that IR are being passed without any deflection inside the smoke sensor. As the value decreases, it means some object (or smoke) has been detected.

How should I make LED and buzzer respond as well ? It would be great if someone can point out my mistake and help me to improve it. :)

Note: Resistors value can be seen in the screenshot of circuit diagram. Rest are as follows:

- Capacitor 100uF, 25V.
- Potentiometer of 10 kilo-ohms.
- Transistors of BC547A

EDIT: I have taken these two actual schematics into consideration in designing this circuit:

1. Connecting Optocoupler 4N35 (smoke sensor) with Arduino. Since the TinkerCad was not having MOC-7811, I have used IC 4N35.

[image]

2. The rest of circuit is same after MOC7811. I have removed 4.7K potentiometer and 100 ohms resistor.

[image]

Arduino Code:

```
int inputPin = 1; // select the input pin for the interrupter
int val = 0; // variable to store the value coming from the sensor

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    val = analogRead(inputPin); // read the value from the sensor
    Serial.println(val); // print the sensor value to the serial monitor
    delay(50);
}
```

Comment: Can you post an actual schematic? And the code..

Comment: Also, judging by the image in your breadboard, you are hooking up your IC's the wrong way. You are shorting out the two sides

Comment: @WesleyLee I have used TinkerCad for simulating the circuit. I have referred two circuits. I'm not having the actual schematic. Though I can share this schematic with the code: https://www.tinkercad.com/things/6OE3dtO7z2L-sizzling-krunk-densor/editel?sharecode=Rl9d0tsDkK6ZLbCVpfx4sqRtbv8mjFBOmKkiM7OyebA=

Comment: @JorenVaes Please refer the above comment. :)

Comment: @Harshit - tinkercad asked me to log in to view anything. Not going to do that.. Just as a heads up, the lack of a schematic and code (and attempt to substitute that with a fritzing-ish drawing) will not help your prospects of a decent answer. Maybe this should be moved to Arduino.SE.

Comment: Okay @WesleyLee. I will ask there. But I have updated my question too. Please have a look. Thanks for the help. I really appreciated it.

Comment: @Harshit If you really breadboard it as shown in the picture above, it won 't work. The two IC's have their opposing pins shorted out. Look up how a breadboard is interconnected.

Comment: The ICs MUST be placed across the center groove, so the top side pins connect to the top groups of five connected holes, and the bottom side pins connect to the bottom groups of five connected holes.  It appears that you don't understand how the breadboard is constructed - what holes are connected together.

Comment: @Harshit - don't cross post, please.

Comment: Thanks @JorenVaes. I didn't noticed that I have shorted ICs opposing pins. It's working now! I have fixed it.